# Value too long for type character varying(3) Django Models

Tags: django, django-models

I can't seem to find out what is happening, the values for paymenttype are 3 characters long, so if anybody could tell me whats the problem with this model I'd be grateful.

```
class PaymentType(models.Model):
    
    INSCRIPTION = 'INS'
    CROSSSFIT = 'CRF'
    FUNCTIONAL = 'FUN'
    KICKBOXING = 'KBX'
    ALL_ACCESS = 'ALL'
    UNSPECIFIED = 'UNS'

    PAYMENT_CHOICES = (
        (INSCRIPTION, 'Inscription'),
        (CROSSSFIT, 'Crossfit'),
        (FUNCTIONAL, 'Functional'),
        (KICKBOXING, 'Kickboxing'),
        (ALL_ACCESS, 'All access'),
        (UNSPECIFIED, 'Unspecified'),
    )


    payment_code = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=PAYMENT_CHOICES, default=UNSPECIFIED)    
    amount = models.FloatField()

class Payment(models.Model):

    payment_type = models.ForeignKey(PaymentType, on_delete=models.SET("UNS"))
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    reference = models.IntegerField()
    athlete = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.payment_type

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('payment-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Comment: How do you get this error ?
When instantiating an object or when creating the migration ?

Comment: When running the migrate command

Comment: Do you have existing data in your database ?

Comment: I used to have entries in Payments but I already deleted them, PaymentType is new to the model.

Comment: That's strange, I don't have any errors when I run the migrate command using your `PaymentType` model.

Comment: I dropped all tables and deleted all migrations and it worked, thank you!